# Редактирование MDDataTable на Python

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

представляю маленький фрагмент своего приложения, которое содержит таблицу, заполняемую из базы данных (базу данных заменил на ведённые данные для таблицы).
В KivyMD есть возможность заполнять таблицу данными, но не могу найти, как сделать возможным заполнять таблицу пользователем или заменять уже введённые данные.
Есть ли такая возможность? и если нет, то каковы альтернативы?

Мне на ум приходит заменить таблицу (те столбцы, где пользователь будет сам записывать значения) на поля для ввода данных. Поля расположить близко друг к другу так, чтобы казалось что это таблица.

```
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.button import *
from kivymd.uix.navigationdrawer import *
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable


class Potatle_mobile(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        app_layout = FloatLayout()

        self.grid = GridLayout(cols= 1)        

        self.table = MDDataTable(
            size_hint= (0.9, 0.6),
            use_pagination= True,
            column_data=[
                ("Desert (100g serving)", dp(70)),
                ("Calories", dp(30)),
                ("Carbs (g)", dp(30)),
                ("Protein (g)", dp(30)),
                ("Iron (%)", dp(30)),
            ],
            row_data=[
                ("Frozen yogurt", "159", "", "", "87"),
                ("Frozen yogurt", "159", "", "", "87"),
            ],
        )

        # 
        app_layout.add_widget(self.table)

        return app_layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Potatle_mobile().run()
```